# Building Objective-C framework for Mac

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, xcodebuild

Ola,

I followed this tutorial to build frameworks for iOS, https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework I was wondering how to convert it to build a framework for Mac. I am stuck on the build script.

```
set -e
set +u
# Avoid recursively calling this script.
if [[ $SF_MASTER_SCRIPT_RUNNING ]]
then
    exit 0
fi
set -u
export SF_MASTER_SCRIPT_RUNNING=1

SF_TARGET_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
SF_EXECUTABLE_PATH="lib${SF_TARGET_NAME}.a"
SF_WRAPPER_NAME="${SF_TARGET_NAME}.framework"

# The following conditionals come from
# https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework

if [[ "$SDK_NAME" =~ ([A-Za-z]+) ]]
then
    SF_SDK_PLATFORM=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
    echo "Could not find platform name from SDK_NAME: $SDK_NAME"
    exit 1
fi

if [[ "$SDK_NAME" =~ ([0-9]+.*$) ]]
then
    SF_SDK_VERSION=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
    echo "Could not find sdk version from SDK_NAME: $SDK_NAME"
    exit 1
fi

if [[ "$SF_SDK_PLATFORM" = "iphoneos" ]]
then
    SF_OTHER_PLATFORM=iphonesimulator
else
    SF_OTHER_PLATFORM=iphoneos
fi

if [[ "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR" =~ (.*)$SF_SDK_PLATFORM$ ]]
then
    SF_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${SF_OTHER_PLATFORM}"
else
    echo "Could not find platform name from build products directory: $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR"
    exit 1
fi

# Build the other platform.
xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" -target "${TARGET_NAME}" -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" -sdk ${SF_OTHER_PLATFORM}${SF_SDK_VERSION} BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}" $ACTION

# Smash the two static libraries into one fat binary and store it in the .framework
lipo -create "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${SF_EXECUTABLE_PATH}" "${SF_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${SF_EXECUTABLE_PATH}" -output "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${SF_WRAPPER_NAME}/Versions/A/${SF_TARGET_NAME}"

# Copy the binary to the other architecture folder to have a complete framework in both.
cp -a "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${SF_WRAPPER_NAME}/Versions/A/${SF_TARGET_NAME}" "${SF_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${SF_WRAPPER_NAME}/Versions/A/${SF_TARGET_NAME}"
```

SF_OTHER_PLATFORM should be macosx for mac I assume, but still seems to break. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

If I adjust the script to run with these variables

```
SF_OTHER_PLATFORM=macosx
SF_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Then I get this error

```
lipo: can't open input file: 10.8/libTestFramework.a (No such file or directory)
Showing first 200 notices only
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Breaks with this if built as is **Could not find platform name from build products directory: /Users/MacbookPro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFramework-awdznuiagjoxvuanuicffewyrfqy/Build/Products/Debug
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1**

Comment: Put clarifications to your question in the question, not in comments.

Comment: Check if the base SDK of you Framework target is correct.